# Add leading zero if number is under 10 in PHP

Tags: php, pagination, preg-replace, leading-zero

I would like to create a pagination with leading zeros, if the number is under 10:
< 07 08 09 10 11 >

My pagination outputs similar HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">&lt;</a>
    <span>7</span>
    <a href="#">8</a>
    <a href="#">9</a>
    <a href="#">10</a>
    <a href="#">11</a>
    <a href="#">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

I am trying to use the `preg_replace` function to catch single digits and to add the leading zero, but I don't know how could I keep the digit:

```
$r = preg_replace('/>[0-9]</', '>01<', $r);
return $r;
```

I solved the problem with `str_replace` but this is ugly:

```
$r = str_replace(array('>1<','>2<','>3<','>4<','>5<','>6<','>7<','>8<','>9<'), array('>01<','>02<','>03<','>04<','>05<','>06<','>07<','>08<','>09<'), $r);
```

Comment: @aynber That question doesn't show how to do when the number is being replaced with `preg_replace()`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, I didn't realize the OP was trying to do it after the HTML was generated.

Comment: It would be best to do this when generating the HTML in the first place, rather than fix it up later.

Comment: I am using a built in function to display the pagination so I have to modify the HTML output

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can achieve it using `sprintf`

```
$numPadded = sprintf("%02d", $num);
echo $numPadded;
```

Comment: Show how to do that in the `preg_replace()`. You'll need to use `preg_replace_callback()`, which seems like overkill for this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture the original number and copy it into the replacement.

```
$r = preg_replace('/>([0-9])</', '>0$1<', $r);
```

That said, it's generally a bad idea to use regular expressions to process HTML. You should use a proper parser such as `DOMDocument`.

Or generate the numbers with leading zeroes when creating the HTML in the first place, using `sprintf()` or `str_pad()`.

Comment: How can I capture the original number to use it in the `preg_replace`?